# filtering specific value with aggregate function in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rstudio, aggregate

[image]

Hi,

I would like to filter the largest datetime values for each customer by the first three digits of mccmnc.

As you can see in the picture, `customer == 'abghsd'` has two different mccmnc values '53208' and '53210'. The **first three digits of mccmnc**, however, are the same (532). So I want to filter customer abghsd's maximum datetime value with `mccmnc = '532'`. For `customer = 'abbaedl'`, I need to filter the maximum datetime for `mccmnc = '623'` and `mccmnc = '451'`.

So may I ask how to give conditions for this problem? 
With the query below, I was able to filter `datetime` by `customer` and `mccmnc`, but I want to filter mccmnc's first three digits.

```
processed <- aggregate(datetime ~ customer + mccmnc, data =raw_data3, max)
```

This is the result that I want to get:

```
Customer       datetime mccmnc
abghsd   20181123222022  53210
abbaedl  20181226121213  62330
abbaedl  20181227191919  45123
```

Thank you.

Comment: please include data so we can help you. Use the `dput(data)` command and include the output in your questions

Comment: What is the algorithm for this? Just grab first three values from `mccmnc`?

Comment: You seem to have serious trouble with your underlying data structure. Is, e.g., `mccmnc` **always exactly** five digits long?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik yeah I need to grab first three values from mccmnc

Answer (score 1):

Editing your original code, you can just add `substr()`:

```
processed <- aggregate(datetime ~ customer + substr(mccmnc, 1, 3), data = raw_data3, max)
```

Alternatively, a `tidyverse` solution:

#### Code

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    # Group by customer ID and first 3 characters of mccmnc 
    group_by(customer, mccmnc_group = substr(mccmnc, 1, 3)) %>%
    # Get the max datetime per group
    summarise(max_datetime = max(datetime)) %>%
    # Put columns in original order
    select(1, 3, 2)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   customer [2]
  customer     max_datetime mccmnc_group
  <fct>               <dbl> <chr>       
1 John Package     20181201 532         
2 Miranda Nuts     20181227 451         
3 Miranda Nuts     20181226 623
```

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(customer = c(rep("John Package", 3), rep("Miranda Nuts", 4)),
           datetime = c(20181123, 20181201, 20181124, 20181125, 20181226, 20181226, 20181227),
           mccmnc = c("532-08", "532-08", "532-10", "623-12", "623-30", "451-21", "451-23"))

> df
      customer datetime mccmnc
1 John Package 20181123 532-08
2 John Package 20181201 532-08
3 John Package 20181124 532-10
4 Miranda Nuts 20181125 623-12
5 Miranda Nuts 20181226 623-30
6 Miranda Nuts 20181226 451-21
7 Miranda Nuts 20181227 451-23
```